# Reponsive navbar issues using media queries

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

As you can see, on different screen sizes my logo is either way out of place or the menu is overlapping with the logo.

I've tried adding different media queries into css but it seems that even if I have different media queries for different rules(e.g. on small phone the logo size should have a width of 100px and on an iphone of 150) it doesen't quite work as intended.
My question is:

Is there a way I can create separate rules of display (for phone logo and menu list should have specific dimensions and on tablets another e.t.c)

here is what i tried so far:

```
@media(max-width:320px) {
    .navbar-brand{
        height:110px;
        width:80px;
    }
    }
@media(max-width:480px) {
    .navbar-brand{
        height:70px;
        width:220px;
    }
    }
```

and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is What You Can do. Most Easiest Way i Can Tell.
Add These 3 lines of code to your IMG.

```
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
```

After Adding These 3 lines of code Your Site Looks like This:-
[image]

in 768 Resolution Case. add new `'class or id'` to navigation.Decrease The `'Width'` and use `'Position'`.You Will Get Your Design in the Way You Want.
Hope This Will Help You

Comment: It fixed my brand problems, but I still cannot fix my navbar not overlapping.I've tried giving an id to the navigation class but it doesent do anything.

Comment: The Overlapping Problem You Are talking about is in resolution 768 right?

Comment: yes, and one li element is overlapped in resolution 1024.

Comment: I Recommend You To Read Bootstrap navigation documentation again.i'm Pretty Sure You Made mistake in making navigation menu.But If You not want to.Please Reply so i can make up solution for this

Comment: I used 2 media queries so I forced the navigation bar to collapse in 1024 resolution and 768 resolution,however this is not an acceptable solution.I posted my code here : bootply.com/QBPosu9mkb –

Comment: i made some editing Here Your Menu Looks Fine.But You Have To add class to last menu item `'li'`.and use `'position:absolute'` to align this  navigation menu item. Carefully add this code to only media queries of 768px resolution. [For CSS Code Click Here](http://i.imgur.com/ceGXsmh.jpg)

Comment: i highly recommend you to try this css code at different resolution and set min and max width for which This css code work.